# R Date conversion from factor

Tags: r, date

I have a factor of a date given in number with the origin 1899-12-30, e.g.

```
dat1 <- factor(42648)
```

If I want to change it to a date format, I'd normally do

```
as.Date(dat1, origin="1899-12-30")
```

but the conversion requires a certain format. Doing

```
as.Date(as.numeric(as.character(dat1)), origin="1899-12-30")
```

works but it seems a little over the top. Is there a shorter way?

Comment: Did you make this a factor or did it turn into a factor when your read it in or ...?  Seems like the shortest way would be to store these as continuous data instead of categorical.

Comment: Yeah, I imported an xlsx file and the column containing dates was converted to factors with the numeric format as underlying.

Comment: It may be that the real question here is how to import the xlsx file to read these as numbers instead of factors.  If so, you could add an example of what your file looks like prior to reading it in and what code you used to read it in with.  A common reason for reading numeric variables as factors in R is having characters stored in the column along with the numbers.

Comment: Actually, I really would like to know, whether there is a way to convert it that way. E.g. `as.Date(dat1, origin="1899-12-30", format=numeric())`

Comment: Unless you fix the issue upon read, what you're doing now with `as.numeric` and `as.character` is pretty much the standard way to do this.  Certainly you could write a function that streamlined things, maybe even something that wraps around `as.Date`.

Comment: Upon importing the sheet, though I can explicitly change the class of the column with `"Date"`, the issue then is, that the origin-date is not the one I'd like to use. So I guess it doesn't make a difference to write a wrap-around or to modify the dates regarding programming...

Comment: why did you choose that value for the origin parameter?